# How to close the presentation without saving it in Python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have to open multiple presentation using a loop, get some data and close it.

I cannot seem to find a way to close the ppt file in python pptx without saving/overwriting it.

I use the following to open the ppt file

```
pptfile = addressList[xyz]
prs = Presentation(pptfile)
slides = prs.slides
```

but I cannot find a way to close to presentation(prs) without saving in order to load the next ppt

I have a temporary work around which is as follows

```
prs.save(r"C:\Users\prashant.kumar\temp.pptx")
```

Since `prs.save` closes the ppt it works fine but I want a better way to close the ppt without creating a temp ppt file.

Is there an attribute of `Presentation` for `python-pptx` which I can use to close the ppt without saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an attribute of Presentation for python-pptx which I can use to close the ppt without saving?

Just... stop using it? pptx doesn't seem to have a `__del__` so if you just stop using it without saving it should not save.

If that doesn't work for some reason (though that would be odd as, again, I don't see where it'd save the modified presentation), you can give pptx a *file object*, which you can close after having loaded the presentation:

```py
pptfile = addressList[xyz]
with open(pptfile, 'rb') as f:
    prs = Presentation(f)
slides = prs.slides
```

it should not be *able* to modify the file then, even if it wants to.

Comment: I can't stop using it. As I said above, I am using a loop where each iteration of loop will use a fresh `prs` for a new PPT file which is stored in `addressList[xyz]` 
So before I assign a new ppt file to `prs` I have to close/clear it before the loop iterates, else python-pptx throws an error

Comment: What error does it throw? Because the documentation of pptx says nothing about closing Presentation objects and `__del__` is not used anywhere and a cursory trawling doesn't seem to show any modification (let alone significant) performed by `save`.

Answer (score 2):

`python-pptx` does not hold a file open while you are working on it. When you call:

```
prs = Presentation(pptfile)
```

The file `pptfile` is opened, read into memory, and closed, all before returning the `Presentation` object. So you can just use the `prs` reference for whatever you need and then abandon it for garbage collection, the same as any other object in Python.

You don't mention in your question a problem with some operation not being permitted because a file is open, so I assume you just thought that would be a problem and haven't actually encountered one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import os

os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM powerpnt.exe")
```

Comment: This really helps stopping all open instances of ppt